# T-SQL - In Single Stored procedure want to pass value(result) of one query to another query as input

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Stored procedure, in which I have to insert 3 strings into 3 different Tables at a time, each string into each of the 3 tables.
In each table, a unique primary key (rowid) would be generated on insertion of the value.
Now, the Primary Key of first two tables is the Foreign key of the Third Table which as you all know, should not be null.

Here in my SP, insertion of value and generation of RowID (PrimaryKey) is done successfully.
Now I have to pass the two primary keys(Rowids) as values/Parameters(foreignkeys) into the third table, which is returning null.

Here is my SP:-

```
    (1st Table)    
   INSERT INTO [kk_admin].[FA_Master](FA_Name,FA_CSession,FA_MSession) Values
             (@FA_Name,@Session_Id,@Session_Id)

   SELECT @**FA_ID=FA_ID** FROM [kk_admin].[FA_Master] where FA_Name=@FA_Name  

    (2nd Table)  
   INSERT INTO [kk_admin].[Dept_Master](Dept_Name,Dept_CSession,Dept_MSession) Values  
   (@Dept_Name,@Session_Id,@Session_Id)  

   SELECT @**Dept_id=Dept_id** from [kk_admin].[Dept_Master] where Dept_Name=@Dept_Name   

   (3rd Table)
   INSERT INTO [kk_admin].[Category_Master] (**FA_Id**,**Dept_Id**,Category_Name,Category_CSession,Category_MSession) Values    (@**FA_ID**,@**Dept_Id**,@Category_Name,@Session_Id,@Session_Id)
```

Hope everyone understood what I have explained.

Plz  Help me,
Iam running out of time. 
  Plz help me.
  Thank You in Advance,
Brightsy

Comment: OK,I will explain u in simple way. I want the result of first & second query, and pass it as parameters to the third query.<br/>SELECT @FA_ID=FA_ID FROM [kk_admin].[FA_Master] where FA_Name=@FA_Name (1st)<br/>SELECT @Dept_id=Dept_id from [kk_admin].[Dept_Master] where Dept_Name=@Dept_Name (2nd) <br/> INSERT INTO [kk_admin].[Category_Master] (FA_Id,Dept_Id,Category_Name,Category_CSession,Category_MSession) Values (@FA_ID,@Dept_Id,@Category_Name,@Session_Id,@Session_Id) (3rd Query).<br/> want to pass the value of FA_ID & Dept_Id as parameter to the insert query. Hope u understood.

Comment: PLz HELP me. Its very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `OUTPUT` clause (assuming you're using SQL Server 2005) to capture the primary key for the two rows you're inserting with the first two queries. You can capture the values into a temporary table. [I previously wrote that you could use a regular variable, but that's not supported.] Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE #FA_Master_ID ( ID int );
CREATE TABLE #Dept_Master_ID ( ID int );

INSERT kk_admin.FA_Master ( FA_Name, FA_CSession, FA_MSession )
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO #FA_Master_ID
VALUES ( @FA_Name, @Session_Id, @Session_Id );

INSERT kk_admin.Dept_Master ( Dept_Name, Dept_CSession, Dept_MSession )
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO #Dept_Master_ID
VALUES ( @Dept_Name, @Session_Id, @Session_Id );

INSERT kk_admin.Category_Master ( **FA_Id**, **Dept_Id**, Category_Name, Category_CSession, Category_MSession )
SELECT  **FA_Id** = ( SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM #FA_Master_ID ),
        **Dept_Id** = ( SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM #Dept_Master_ID ),
        Category_Name = @Category_Name,
        Category_CSession = @Session_Id,
        Category_MSession = @Session_Id;
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Kenny for Helping me. I working on ur code and let u know.

Comment: sORRY BUT THE OUTPUT METHOD IS NOT WORKING, iAM WORKING ON SQL SERVER 2005 ONLY. AND ALSO I COULDNT UNDERSTAND

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause is supported in SQL Server 2005 (but not earlier versions) and it lets you reference rows you're inserting (if used in an INSERT query). In this case, we're inserting data from the rows you're inserting into temporary tables so you can use that data in subsequent queries.

Comment: Here are some things to check when you try to use my example code: (1) change the `INSERTED.ID` expression in the first two queries to `INSERTED.x` where `x` is the actual 'ID' column for the `FA_Master` and `Dept_Master` tables; (2) replace the columns `**FA_Id**` and `**Dept_Id**` with the actual column names for the table `Category_Master`.